# How to create a multi select with more than 8 tables and special conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to create a search where you can search Book and Movie names in different languages. 
I have already tried to use `UNION` and `UNION ALL` but that doesn't work because my main Tables have a different number of columns. I also tried `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` but that also doesn't work because it repeated some Titles which should not be repeated, while I'm using a while loop.

```
movie
---------------------------------------------------------
movie_id|original_movie_title|serial_id|genre|type|aired|
---------------------------------------------------------
   1    |Harry Potter        |    1    | ... |... | ... |
   2    |Kimi No Na Wa       |    2    | ... |... | ... |
   3    |Avengers            |    3    | ... |... | ... |

book
--------------------------------------------------
book_id|original_book_title|serial_id|genre|aired|
--------------------------------------------------
   1   |GoT Fire & Blood   |    4    | ... | ... |
   2   |Kimi No Na Wa      |    2    | ... | ... |
   3   |The Jungle Book    |    5    | ... | ... |

movie_de                             movie_ru
------------------------------       ------------------------------
de_movie_id|movie_id|de_title|       ru_movie_id|movie_id|ru_title|
   1       |    1   |Harry Potter       1       |    1   |гарри поттер
   2       |    2   |Your Name          2       |    2   |Твоё имя

movie_jp                               movie_en
------------------------------         ------------------------------
jp_movie_id|movie_id|jp_title|         en_movie_id|movie_id|en_title|
   1       |    1   |ハリー・ポッターと    1        |    1   |Harry Potter    
   2       |    3   |アベンジャーズ        2       |    2    |Your Name.
   3       |    2   |君の名は。           3        |    3   |The Avengers

book_de                              book_ru
------------------------------       ------------------------------
de_book_id|book_id|de_title|         ru_book_id|book_id|ru_title|
   1      |    1  |GoT Feuer & Blut   1        |    1  |GoT огонь и кровь    
   2      |    2  |Your Name.         2        |    2  |Твоё имя
   3      |    3  |Das Dschungel B.                  

book_jp                              book_en
------------------------------       ------------------------------
jp_book_id|book_id|jp_title|         en_book_id|book_id|en_title|
   1      |  2   |君の名は。            1       |   1   |GoT Fire & Blood    
   2      |  1   |GoT 血と火            2       |   2   |Your Name.
                                       3       |   3   |The Jungle Book
```

Now if I enter the letter "o" in my search, I want that all language Titles get listed and ordered by name, but all Language Titles should have the same "Basic Information" from the main table. So if I search for "の" all Titles with this Letter should get listed and right next to them, should stand the genre and aired Date, like:

Searched for "o"

```
 - Harry Potter        |Genre:...  |Aired:...  (From movie_de)
 - Kimi No Na Wa       |Genre:...  |Aired:...  (From original_movie_title)
 - Your Name           |Genre:...  |Aired:...  (From book_en)
 - гарри поттер        |Genre:...  |Aired:...  (From movie_ru)
 - Your Name           |Genre:...  |Aired:...  (From movie_en)
 - The Jungle Book     |Genre:...  |Aired:...  (From original_book_title)
 - Harry Potter        |Genre:...  |Aired:...  (From movie_en)
 - Got Fire & Blood    |Genre:...  |Aired:...  (From book_en)
 - Got Feuer & Blut    |Genre:...  |Aired:...  (From book_de)
```

Comment: Sounds like you were on the right track with the UNION / UNION ALL ideas.... to get around having different number of columns is just pad the ones with less columns by selecting null, or empty literal string for each of the columns the other tables have.

Comment: Why don't you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 3):

I know `JOIN` and `UNION` work. However, I think you should create a cached table and search only on that table instead. You can create a table with a structure like this:

```
search_data
------------------------------
type |id|language|title
------------------------------
book |1 |en      |GoT Fire & Blood
book |1 |jp      |GoT 血と火
movie|3 |en      |The Avengers
movie|3 |jp      |アベンジャーズ
```

Remember that the `title` column should be indexed for full-text searches. Now, you can search on the `title` column of the `search_data` and retrieve the item details from the original table (`books` or `movies`) based on the `type`, `id` and `language` columns. The `search_data` table should be updated via PHP scripts, a cron job or MySQL triggers everytime your tables are updated.

Comment: Upvoted for the better approach over my response. Just wanted to note that you will need to recode to UTF-8 sequences if you are going to use `LIKE` search on the title column, and that it should be cast to `NVARCHAR` if your English/German title pages are set to `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to select the correct amount of columns with consistent naming, then `UNION ALL` should work with no problems. A small sample below:

```
SELECT
    original_movie_title as title,
    genre, aired
FROM movie
WHERE original_movie_title LIKE '%o%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    title.de_title as title, 
    movie.genre, movie.aired
FROM movie_de as title
LEFT JOIN movie
ON title.movie_id = movie.movie_id
WHERE title.de_title LIKE '%o%'
```

Since you tagged MySQL, note that unicode characters need to be escaped in your LIKE, which can get complicated and you might need to fiddle around with the encoding. If you are using SQL Server / TSQL, you can use the `N` prefix to your strings to indicate NVARCHAR.